# MongoDB Document Re-shaping

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This question comes out of (as mine usually do) perusing the questions asked on SO and as such, raising another question for myself. So apart from the *learning exercise* in working towards a solution for a problem, I find that another question pops up, such as this.

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21913335/2313887) as yet remains unaccepted by the OP, and indeed has not been clarified as to what *"they"* wanted to achieve. But I did give *my interpretation*, in both the **simple** and **long** forms of arriving at a solution.

The process, in the end, has left me wondering that considering the **long** form of the solution, would there be some new feature to be introduced in the next (Currently expecting 2.6) MongoDB release, using the additional aggregation operators that have been introduced.

So the case is as follows:

### Sample Documents

```js
{
    "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
    "tracked_item_name" : "Word",
    "duration" : 9540
}
{
    "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
    "tracked_item_name" : "Excel",
    "duration" : 4000
}
{
    "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
    "tracked_item_name" : "Notepad",
    "duration" : 4000
}
{
    "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
    "tracked_item_name" : "Facebook",
    "duration" : 7920
}
{
    "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
    "tracked_item_name" : "Twitter",
    "duration" : 5555
}
{
    "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
    "tracked_item_name" : "Digital Blasphemy",
    "duration" : 8000
}
```

### Desired Result

The **top two** results by each type, ordered by the total duration. Even though this is a *small* sample, duration is considered to be a **$sum** of many items.

```js
{ 
    "tracked_item_type": "Site",
    "tracked_item_name": "Digital Blasphemy",
    "duration" : 8000
}
{ 
    "tracked_item_type": "Site",
    "tracked_item_name": "Facebook",
    "duration" : 7920
}
{ 
    "tracked_item_type": "Software",
    "tracked_item_name": "Word",
    "duration" : 9540
}
{ 
    "tracked_item_type": "Software",
    "tracked_item_name": "Notepad",
    "duration" : 4000
}
```

### Aggregate Solution

This was my **lengthy** way to solve the problem

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Group on the types and "sum" of duration
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {
            "tracked_item_type": "$tracked_item_type",
            "tracked_item_name": "$tracked_item_name"
         },
        "duration": {"$sum": "$duration"}
    }},

    // Sort by type and duration descending
    {"$sort": { "_id.tracked_item_type": 1, "duration": -1 }},

    /* The fun part */

    // Re-shape results to "sites" and "software" arrays 
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "sites": {"$push":
            {"$cond": [
                {"$eq": ["$_id.tracked_item_type", "Site" ]},
                { "_id": "$_id", "duration": "$duration" },
                null
            ]}
        },
        "software": {"$push":
            {"$cond": [
                {"$eq": ["$_id.tracked_item_type", "Software" ]},
                { "_id": "$_id", "duration": "$duration" },
                null
            ]}
        }
    }},


    // Remove the null values for "software"
    {"$unwind": "$software"},
    {"$match": { "software": {"$ne": null} }},
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "software": {"$push": "$software"}, 
        "sites": {"$first": "$sites"} 
    }},

    // Remove the null values for "sites"
    {"$unwind": "$sites"},
    {"$match": { "sites": {"$ne": null} }},
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "software": {"$first": "$software"},
        "sites": {"$push": "$sites"} 
    }},


    // Project out software and limit to the *top* 2 results
    {"$unwind": "$software"},
    {"$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "_id": { "_id": "$software._id", "duration": "$software.duration" },
        "sites": "$sites"
    }},
    {"$limit" : 2},


    // Project sites, grouping multiple software per key, requires a sort
    // then limit the *top* 2 results
    {"$unwind": "$sites"},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": { "_id": "$sites._id", "duration": "$sites.duration" },
        "software": {"$push": "$_id" }
    }},
    {"$sort": { "_id.duration": -1 }},
    {"$limit": 2}

])
```

### The "Not quite there yet" Output

And the point where aggregation falls short of getting to the **final** result. At least to my current understanding.

```js
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
                    "tracked_item_name" : "Digital Blasphemy"
                 },
                 "duration" : 8000
           },
            "software" : [
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                        "tracked_item_name" : "Word"
                    },
                    "duration" : 9540
                },

                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                        "tracked_item_name" : "Notepad"
                    },
                    "duration" : 4000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
                    "tracked_item_name" : "Facebook"
                },
                "duration" : 7920
            },
            "software" : [
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                        "tracked_item_name" : "Word"
                    },
                    "duration" : 9540
                },
                {
                    "_id" : {
                        "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                        "tracked_item_name" : "Notepad"
                    },
                    "duration" : 4000
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

This all seemed very reasonable (to Me anyway) that the result, while not **complete** could be *post-processed* in code in order to *massage* it into the desired form.

But indeed, it seems an exercise, and a point of intrigue as to whether this **could** be achieved with the use of any **upcoming** features for aggregation (or possibly another technique that has eluded me) to get to the desired result form.

So feel free to answer with any, suggestions / pointers as to how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an aggregation that finds the top two by duration in each category (it does break "ties" arbitrarily, which seems to be in line with your sample output):

```
var pregroup = { "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "type" : "$tracked_item_type",
            "name" : "$tracked_item_name"
        },
        "duration" : {
            "$sum" : "$duration"
        }
    }
};
var sort = { "$sort" : { "_id.type" : 1, "duration" : -1 } };
var group1 = { "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id.type",
        "num1" : {
            "$first" : {
                "name" : "$_id.name",
                "dur" : "$duration"
            }
        },
        "other" : {
            "$push" : {
                "name" : "$_id.name",
                "dur" : "$duration"
            }
        },
    "all" : {
        "$push" : {
            "name" : "$_id.name",
            "dur" : "$duration"
        }
    }
    }
};
var unwind = { "$unwind" : "$other" };
project = {
    "$project" : {
        "keep" : {
            "$ne" : [
                "$num1.name",
                "$other.name"
            ]
        },
        "num1" : 1,
        "all" : 1,
        "other" : 1
    }
};
var match = { "$match" : { "keep" : true } };
var sort2 = { "$sort" : { "_id" : 1, "other.dur" : -1 } };
var group2 = { "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        "numberOne" : {
            "$first" : "$num1"
        },
        "numberTwo" : {
            "$first" : "$other"
        },
    "all" : {
        "$first" : "$all"
    }
    }
};
unwind2 = { "$unwind" : "$all" };
project2 = { "$project" : {
    "_id" : 0,
    "tracked_item_type" : "$_id",
    "tracked_item_name" : {
        "$cond" : [
            {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$all.name",
                            "$numberOne.name"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$all.name",
                            "$numberTwo.name"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "$all.name",
            null
        ]
    },
    "duration" : {
        "$cond" : [
            {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$all.name",
                            "$numberOne.name"
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "$eq" : [
                            "$all.name",
                            "$numberTwo.name"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "$all.dur",
            null
        ]
    }
}
}
match2 = { "$match" : { "tracked_item_name" : { "$ne" : null } } };
```

Running this with your sample data:

```
db.top2.aggregate(pregroup, sort, group1, unwind, project, match, sort2, group2, unwind2, project2, match2).toArray()
[
    {
        "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
        "tracked_item_name" : "Word",
        "duration" : 9540
    },
    {
        "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
        "tracked_item_name" : "Notepad",
        "duration" : 4000
    },
    {
        "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
        "tracked_item_name" : "Digital Blasphemy",
        "duration" : 8000
    },
    {
        "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
        "tracked_item_name" : "Facebook",
        "duration" : 7920
    }
]
```

This will work with arbitrary number of domains (different tracked item type values) and you don't need to know all their names in advance.  However, to generalize it to top three, top four, top five, etc. will add four more stages for each additional top "N" value - not very practical or pretty.

Please [vote up this jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377) to get a more native implementation of "top N" functionality in the aggregation framework.

Comment: A very novel approach. Though not quite in the spirit of the question, which is get to the **"Desired Result"** as shown there, and not to something that approximates that form. Nonetheless, well done. As you say, this approach does have the advantage of **not** being tied to knowing the domain values up-front, albeit with it's own restriction on the number of items to filter. But back to the "spirit", there would not even appear to be a soon to be released feature that could *transform* from these results into the desired form. You are right of course, we need limit functions on grouping.

Comment: I'm not sure why this isn't within the spirit - which I would think be to get top two results for each domain.

Comment: The Desired Result was quite clear in the question, which had also arrived at an approximation, but not actually results, as with here for the **record** type of layout the result would need to be massaged in code. That doesn't detract from your own approach, as I have already said. You know as well as I do that if the grouped results **could** be limited then this is an easy solve. But they can't. There's no prestige in this for me. I just wanted to see if there was some way to achieve the actual document form as was shown. But hey, you may get up-voted and get some bounty.

Comment: The problem with the format you want is it makes it hard to arbitrarily break ties (now that I think about it, maybe it's not correct to keep one of equal values for "2nd" maybe to keep additional entries if there is a tie is actually correct, otherwise you're arguably not doing "the right thing")

Comment: I've been meaning to write up the "top-N" workaround for my blog, I guess now I don't have an excuse not to.

Comment: You didn't tag me so I didn't see this. Can I suggest that this **would** be an appropriate case for a **separate** answer. Due to the flow of comments, and mostly as I would get this better than most people, but even I found this very hard to follow. Hopping between **two** listings was playing with my eyes after a bit. Also note that you are returning an **extra** result.

Comment: @NeilLunn Extra result is one that arguably *should* be returned - when there are two scores that are tied for second, I display both of them.  If you have three values with the same top duration, would you rather arbitrarily show two of them?

Comment: Without this becoming protracted, the top 2 results are stated in the question. The sample had the same value for this very reason. Yes, it's a trap. But please consider what I said in the previous comment, as I think a separate answer stands on it's own. Otherwise the comment chain here becomes confusing to the reader.

Comment: @NeilLunn combined the two into an answer that gives the format you want.

Comment: I haven't got around to really looking at this as yet, but I'll take your word for it. I think you deserve a bounty on this if for nothing else, time and effort that I never applied. And the commentary is somewhat there to explain the pros / cons of approaches. So well done.

Answer (score 0):

### Got my own answer in first!

I wasn't expecting that, but there is an answer that can be found in the implementation of **2.6** which includes some great new [Set Operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation-set/).

So what I thought about (eventually) was that the problem came down to having **two** separate lists that need to be **one**, so how to **merge** these items so that they all fall under **one** field. So there **is** the *obvious* operator for this, **[`$setUnion`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion)**.

Here's the new fragment first, which I'll explain in parts:

```js
// So this part just "normalizes" a little so we get one record that essentially has
// two arrays in it
{"$group": { 
    _id: { _id: null, software: "$software"  },
    sites: {$push:"$_id" }
}},
```

And the resulting document:

```js
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : null,
        "software" : [
             {
                 "_id" : {
                     "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                     "tracked_item_name" : "Word"
                 },
             "duration" : 9540
             },
             {
                 "_id" : {
                     "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                     "tracked_item_name" : "Notepad"
             },
             "duration" : 4000
         }
        ]
    },
    "sites" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
                "tracked_item_name" : "Digital Blasphemy"
            },
            "duration" : 8000
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
                "tracked_item_name" : "Facebook"
            },
            "duration" : 7920
        }
    ]
}
```

So that document, which is arguably a **better** form of the *result* than where I left of before, 
considering the items are no longer duplicated, essentially has the **two** lists we want to **merge** as **one**. So all there is to do now is use the operator that facilitates this **merge**:

```js
// Then we just project with a new field, and the "$setUnion" of the two arrays
{"$project": { 
    "_id": 0,
    "records": {"$setUnion": ["$_id.software", "$sites"]} 
}},
```

And that brings us to here:

```js
{
    "records" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
                "tracked_item_name" : "Facebook"
            },
            "duration" : 7920
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                "tracked_item_name" : "Word"
            },
            "duration" : 9540
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "tracked_item_type" : "Site",
                "tracked_item_name" : "Digital Blasphemy"
            },
            "duration" : 8000
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "tracked_item_type" : "Software",
                "tracked_item_name" : "Notepad"
            },
            "duration" : 4000
        }
    ]
}
```

And basically that's it. Now we just have the four items, so with a little "*unwinding*", *projection* and a *sort*, we'll get the **exact** result that I was looking for.

So here's the whole thing, just for the record:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Group on the types and "sum" of duration
    {"$group": {
        "_id": {
            "tracked_item_type": "$tracked_item_type",
            "tracked_item_name": "$tracked_item_name"
         },
        "duration": {"$sum": "$duration"}
    }},

    // Sort by type and duration descending
    {"$sort": { "_id.tracked_item_type": 1, "duration": -1 }},

    /* The fun part */

    // Re-shape results to "sites" and "software" arrays 
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": null,
        "sites": {"$push":
            {"$cond": [
                {"$eq": ["$_id.tracked_item_type", "Site" ]},
                { "_id": "$_id", "duration": "$duration" },
                null
            ]}
        },
        "software": {"$push":
            {"$cond": [
                {"$eq": ["$_id.tracked_item_type", "Software" ]},
                { "_id": "$_id", "duration": "$duration" },
                null
            ]}
        }
    }},


    // Remove the null values for "software"
    {"$unwind": "$software"},
    {"$match": { "software": {"$ne": null} }},
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "software": {"$push": "$software"}, 
        "sites": {"$first": "$sites"} 
    }},

    // Remove the null values for "sites"
    {"$unwind": "$sites"},
    {"$match": { "sites": {"$ne": null} }},
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "software": {"$first": "$software"},
        "sites": {"$push": "$sites"} 
    }},


    // Project out software and limit to the *top* 2 results
    {"$unwind": "$software"},
    {"$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
        "_id": { "_id": "$software._id", "duration": "$software.duration" },
        "sites": "$sites"
    }},
    {"$limit" : 2},


    // Project sites, grouping multiple software per key, requires a sort
    // then limit the *top* 2 results
    {"$unwind": "$sites"},
    {"$group": {
        "_id": { "_id": "$sites._id", "duration": "$sites.duration" },
        "software": {"$push": "$_id" }
    }},
    {"$sort": { "_id.duration": -1 }},
    {"$limit": 2},

    // So this part just "normalizes" a little so we get one record that
    // essentially has two arrays in it
    {"$group": { 
        _id: { _id: null, software: "$software"  },
        sites: {$push:"$_id" }
    }},

    // Then we just project with a new field, and the "$setUnion" of the two arrays
    {"$project": { 
        "_id": 0,
       "records": {"$setUnion": ["$_id.software", "$sites"]} 
    }},

    // Unwind the array to documents
    {"$unwind": "$records"},

    // Shape the final output
    {"$project": { 
        "tracked_item_type": "$records._id.tracked_item_type",
        "tracked_item_name": "$records._id.tracked_item_name",
        "duration": "$records.duration"
    }},

     // Final sort on the result
    {"$sort": { "tracked_item_type": 1, "duration": -1 }} 

])
```

Obviously there is a *drop-off* point where the whole approach becomes impractical, as the general premise is derived from being able to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) all of the documents into their own arrays in order that the **top** results can then *be pulled out* by eventually calling [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) on those results.

As such, where there would be a **large** number of results for each *"category"*, it is then likely a more practical approach to process the *"category"* individually, and then simply limit *each* of those results to the **top two** items that are required.

But as an exercise, at **least** I know now that this **can** be done. Hope this was all useful to someone.

I Am **Still** interested to see if anyone has another approach though.

Comment: you don't need set operators to get to the answer. the (rather ugly) solution is possible using only 2.4 features of aggregation framework.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I think that was mentioned in the question. And the question shows the result to a **certain** stage. But this was/is all about getting to the desired result. Your own submission for your own approach is welcome/encouraged

Answer (score 0):

Since mongoDB version 3.2, this can be simply done with `$slice`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        tracked_item_type: "$tracked_item_type",
        tracked_item_name: "$tracked_item_name"
      },
      duration: {$sum: "$duration"}
    }
  },
  {$sort: {"_id.tracked_item_type": 1, "duration": -1}},
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.tracked_item_type",
      data: {
        $push: {
          tracked_item_name: "$_id.tracked_item_name",
          tracked_item_type: "$_id.tracked_item_type",
          duration: "$duration"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {data: {$slice: ["$data", 2]}, _id: 0}},
  {$unwind: "$data"},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$data"}
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LxKUJ098cGr)