# In mongoDB can I efficiently group documents into groups of a set size?

Tags: mongodb, statistics, aggregation-framework

I need to group data into subgroups of a set size.  Like if there are 6 records, ordered by date.

`[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

and I have a subgroup size of 2.  I would end up with an array(length of 3) of arrays(each length 2):

`[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

Nothing about the record factors into the grouping, just how they are ordered over all and the subgroup size.

Does the aggregation framework have something that would help with this?

Comment: Good question. Not impossible but there is nothing that actually really helps as yet. For something of a discussion on this, [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21949521/2313887)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to currently do this is with mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var result = [];

        var x = 0;
        for ( x=0; x < Math.floor( this.array.length / 2 ); x+2 ) {
            result.push( this.array.slice( x, x+2 ) );
        }

        var diff = Math.ceil( this.array.length ) 
                   - Math.floor( this.array.length );

        if ( diff != 1 )
            result.push( this.array.slice( x, x+diff ) );

        emit( this._id, result );
    },
    function(){},
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 }
    }
);
```

Or basically something along those lines.

The aggregation framework does not do `slice` type operations well, but JavaScript processes do, especially in this case.